# how to get X,Y coordinates of a movieclip (inside another movieclip) but relative to the _root?

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2, flash-cs3

I have a movieclip inside another movieclip...

```
//create on the stage an empty movieclip... 
var mc_container:MovieClip = _root.createEmptyMovieClip("container_name", _root.getNextHighestDepth());

//new position on the stage...
mc_container._x = 200;
mc_container._y = 200;

//create a movieclip inside the main movieclip...
var mc_inside:MovieClip = mc_container.attachMovie("mc_from_library", "mc_name", mc_container.getNextHighestDepth(), {_x:0, _y:0, _alpha:100});
```

I can get mc_inside._x and mc_inside._y properties relative to the container movieclip, but how can I get the `mc_inside._x` and `mc_inside._y` relative to the `_root` (the stage)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use localToGlobal:

```
var point:Object = {x:myClip.inner_mc._x, y:myClip.inner_mc._y};
myClip.inner_mc.localToGlobal(point);
trace(point.x)
trace(point.y)
```

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as2/reference/flashlite/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118ccf9c47f-7d06.html